# run Pentaho transformation from Pan fails

Tags: pentaho, etl

I get an "not recognised as an internal or external command " error message when I run the following command:

```
C:\pdi-ce>Pan.bat /file=c:\pdi_labs\matches.ktr usa_201210.txt
```

pentaho 4.4.0 community edition is installed in :
    C:\pdi-ce
transformation and files are saved in :

```
C:\pdi_labs\
```

Any hint to run the transformation from Pan since I am able to run it from Spoon.

regards

Comment: Did the below solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cd /C:/pdi-ce/
Pan.bat /file:"c:\pdi_labs\matches.ktr" /usa_201210.txt

Answer (score 0):

Generally Pentaho kettle creates another wrapper folder "data-integration" in installation directory. Check whether Pan.bat exists in the directory. If not cd to the directory which has it.

```
Pan.bat -file="c:\pdi_labs\matches.ktr" > usa_201210.txt
```

Assuming usa_201210.txt is the log file.

I would recommend starting pan.bat in a different shell and make it wait until it completes as below.

```
start /wait cmd  "c:\pdi-ce\Pan.bat -file=c:\pdi_labs\matches.ktr > usa_201210.txt"
```

Comment: yes I referred to their documentation and cd to the directory where the Pan.bat is (code 1) and then run the transformation (code 2). and it worked. Thanks for your input anyway